# What is wrong with io.h, getting errors?

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, header

This is straight out of my textbook, not sure what caused this. It worked before...

Book code I am using:

```
; Input x and y, call procedure to evaluate 3*x+7*y, display result
; Author:  R. Detmer
; Date:    6/2013
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096

.DATA
number1 DWORD   ?
number2 DWORD   ?
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number x", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter second number y", 0
string  BYTE    20 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "3*x+7*y", 0
result  BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, string, 20      ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string          ; convert to integer
        mov     number1, eax    ; store in memory

        input   prompt2, string, 20      ; repeat for second number
        atod    string
        mov     number2, eax

        push    number2         ; 2nd parameter
        push    number1         ; 1st parameter
        call    fctn1           ; fctn1(number1, number2)
        add     esp, 8          ; remove parameters from stack

        dtoa    result, eax     ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, result  ; output label and result

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP

; int fctn1(int x, int y)
; returns 3*x+7*y
fctn1   PROC
        push    ebp             ; save base pointer
        mov     ebp, esp        ; establish stack frame
        push    ebx             ; save EBX

        mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ; x
        imul    eax, 3          ; 3*x
        mov     ebx, [ebp+12]   ; y
        imul    ebx, 7          ; 7*y
        add     eax, ebx        ; 3*x + 7*y

        pop     ebx             ; restore EBX
        pop     ebp             ; restore EBP
        ret                     ; return      
fctn1   ENDP

END
```

Errors:

```
Error   101 error A1012: error count exceeds 100; stopping assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h 102 1   console32
Error   3   error A2008: syntax error : *   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h 3   1   console32
Error   13  error A2044: invalid character in file  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h 14  1   console32
Error   102 error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Source.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt /Fl /TaSource.asm" exited with code 1.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 49  5   console32
```

I removed duplicate erros to make it look cleaner/neater.
I attempted to edit the header file to remove the comments, but I don't have rights to write to it. I also don't think it's necessary to edit this file, because it used to work. And I am using the books files and code.

I tried this on my laptop also and it gives me the same errors. I am using visual studio 2012 on both machines.

If you need more info let me know.

Using io.h in a windows32 assembly program.
Open VS --> New Project --> c/c++ --> Windows32 (NOT console32) --> blank project.
In solution explorer right click sources folder --> add new item --> c++ file (.cpp) and give it a name of your choice with the extension .asm instead of .cpp.
code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
firstInput DWORD    ?                       ; Reserve DWORD sized named memory for 1st input
secondInput DWORD   ?                       ; Reserve DWORD sized named memory for 2nd input
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number",  0    ; Prompt user for the first input
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter second number", 0    ; Prompt user for the second input
inputString  BYTE    11 DUP (?)             ; Reserve memory for to store inputs 
                                            ; as integer max integer is 10 digits big
resultLbl BYTE  "GCD", 0                    ; label for dialogBox

resultLb2 BYTE  "The GCD is:"               ; String to be diplayed in the dialogBox
gcdResult BYTE  10 DUP (?), 0               ; to display " The GCD is:" and then gcdInput

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    ;************************ GET FIRST INPUT ************************
        input   prompt1, inputString, 11    ; read ASCII characters
                                            ; Max length for integer is 10 digits
        atod    inputString                 ; convert to integer
        mov     firstInput, eax             ; store in memory
    ;************************ GET SECOND INPUT ***********************
                                            ; repeat for second number
        input   prompt2, inputString, 11    ; read ASCII characters
        atod    inputString                 ; convert to integer
        mov     secondInput, eax            ; store in memory

        ;******************** THEORY IN PSUDOCODE  *******************
        ; gcdInput is firstInput
        ; remainder is secondInput
        ; loop:
        ; dividend is gcdInput
        ; gcdInput is remainder
        ; 
        ; firstInput and secondInput are reserved memory
        ; dividend is stored in  EAX ---> numerator
        ; gcdInput is stored in  EBX ---> denominator       
        ; remainder is stored in EDX ---> remainder
        ; quotient  is stored in EAX ---> quotient      
        ; EAX/EBX ---> quotient will be stored in EAX
        ;             remainder will be stored in EDX
        ;             based on CPU logic
    ;************************ FIND GCD OF 2 NUMBERS ******************
        mov     EBX, firstInput     ; Copy named memory to EBX
        mov     EDX, secondInput    ; Copy named memory to EDX 

findTheGCD:                 ; DO
        mov     EAX, EBX    ;   Copy gcdInput to EAX. Second pass and so on will
                            ;   copy the denominator to the numerator
        mov     EBX, EDX    ;   Copy remainder to EBX Second pass and so on will
                            ;   copy the remainder to the denominator
        mov     EDX, 0      ;   cdq is for signed, so instead of cdq move 0 to EDX.
                            ;   cdq expands EAX to EDX:EAX filling EDX with the sign bit
                            ;   Since our numbers are positive our sign bit is 0
                            ;   So filling EDX with 0's is the same as cdq would do.
                            ;   We are not using cdq and we are using div because we 
                            ;   are working with unsigned integers. 
                            ;   Clear out previous remainder
        div     EBX         ;   Divide EDX:EAX/EBX (dividend/gcdInput)
                            ;   second pass and so on will divide
                            ;   the denominator by the numerator repeatedly
                            ;   until the remainder is 0
                            ;   Quotient does not matter in this situation
                            ;   After the division process EAX will contain the quotient
                            ;   And EDX will contain the remainder, thus the 0's we filled
                            ;   it with will be overwritten with the remainder
        cmp     EDX, 0      ;   Compare EDX (remainder) to 0
                            ;   Since the 0's were overwritten with the remainder after the division
                            ;   the compare will see the new remainder NOT the 0's that was in it before!!
        jne     findTheGCD  ; UNTIL ( remainder == 0 )

    ;************************ PRINT THE GCD TO SCREEN ******************     
        dtoa    gcdResult, EBX        ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, resultLb2  ; output label and gcd string

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END
```

**Using io.h in a windows32 assembly program.**
Open VS --> New Project --> c/c++ --> Windows32 (NOT console32) --> blank project.
In solution explorer right click sources folder --> add new item --> c++ file (.cpp) and give it a name of your choice with the extension .asm instead of .cpp.
code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
firstInput DWORD    ?                       ; Reserve DWORD sized named memory for 1st input
secondInput DWORD   ?                       ; Reserve DWORD sized named memory for 2nd input
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter first number",  0    ; Prompt user for the first input
prompt2 BYTE    "Enter second number", 0    ; Prompt user for the second input
inputString  BYTE    11 DUP (?)             ; Reserve memory for to store inputs 
                                            ; as integer max integer is 10 digits big
resultLbl BYTE  "GCD", 0                    ; label for dialogBox

resultLb2 BYTE  "The GCD is:"               ; String to be diplayed in the dialogBox
gcdResult BYTE  10 DUP (?), 0               ; to display " The GCD is:" and then gcdInput

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    ;************************ GET FIRST INPUT ************************
        input   prompt1, inputString, 11    ; read ASCII characters
                                            ; Max length for integer is 10 digits
        atod    inputString                 ; convert to integer
        mov     firstInput, eax             ; store in memory
    ;************************ GET SECOND INPUT ***********************
                                            ; repeat for second number
        input   prompt2, inputString, 11    ; read ASCII characters
        atod    inputString                 ; convert to integer
        mov     secondInput, eax            ; store in memory

        ;******************** THEORY IN PSUDOCODE  *******************
        ; gcdInput is firstInput
        ; remainder is secondInput
        ; loop:
        ; dividend is gcdInput
        ; gcdInput is remainder
        ; 
        ; firstInput and secondInput are reserved memory
        ; dividend is stored in  EAX ---> numerator
        ; gcdInput is stored in  EBX ---> denominator       
        ; remainder is stored in EDX ---> remainder
        ; quotient  is stored in EAX ---> quotient      
        ; EAX/EBX ---> quotient will be stored in EAX
        ;             remainder will be stored in EDX
        ;             based on CPU logic
    ;************************ FIND GCD OF 2 NUMBERS ******************
        mov     EBX, firstInput     ; Copy named memory to EBX
        mov     EDX, secondInput    ; Copy named memory to EDX 

findTheGCD:                 ; DO
        mov     EAX, EBX    ;   Copy gcdInput to EAX. Second pass and so on will
                            ;   copy the denominator to the numerator
        mov     EBX, EDX    ;   Copy remainder to EBX Second pass and so on will
                            ;   copy the remainder to the denominator
        mov     EDX, 0      ;   cdq is for signed, so instead of cdq move 0 to EDX.
                            ;   cdq expands EAX to EDX:EAX filling EDX with the sign bit
                            ;   Since our numbers are positive our sign bit is 0
                            ;   So filling EDX with 0's is the same as cdq would do.
                            ;   We are not using cdq and we are using div because we 
                            ;   are working with unsigned integers. 
                            ;   Clear out previous remainder
        div     EBX         ;   Divide EDX:EAX/EBX (dividend/gcdInput)
                            ;   second pass and so on will divide
                            ;   the denominator by the numerator repeatedly
                            ;   until the remainder is 0
                            ;   Quotient does not matter in this situation
                            ;   After the division process EAX will contain the quotient
                            ;   And EDX will contain the remainder, thus the 0's we filled
                            ;   it with will be overwritten with the remainder
        cmp     EDX, 0      ;   Compare EDX (remainder) to 0
                            ;   Since the 0's were overwritten with the remainder after the division
                            ;   the compare will see the new remainder NOT the 0's that was in it before!!
        jne     findTheGCD  ; UNTIL ( remainder == 0 )

    ;************************ PRINT THE GCD TO SCREEN ******************     
        dtoa    gcdResult, EBX        ; convert to ASCII characters
        output  resultLbl, resultLb2  ; output label and gcd string

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END
```

Comment: The problem is that `io.h` is written in C and so MASM can't assemble it. You can only include files written in assembly language. It's likely that the file you should be including has a different name, like `io.inc` or `io.asm`.

Comment: @RossRidge I'm not sure about that, I do know it's written in C. However, it works in windows 32 application, not console 32 application. And you can NOT use io.h in console assembly apps. io.h does work in windows32 assembly programs though.

Comment: If you look at the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\io.h` you'll see that's written in C. It declares a number of low level file I/O functions that are provided by the Microsoft C runtime library. It can be used in both GUI and console Windows applications, but it can only be used with a C or C++ compiler. If you try to assemble it with MASM it will generate countless errors, just as you have encountered. It doesn't matter if whether its a console or GUI application as that makes no difference to MASM. It doesn't understand C either way.

Comment: I could show you a windows32 assembly program I made that uses IO.h and works, if you'd like. I've made about 3 that work.... Google it dude.

Comment: @RossRidge buy this book: http://amzn.com/128403612X You need to study that book. You need to follow the programming exercises where you use io.h in windows32 assembly program. I am telling you, it works. The code is straight of of the book,and it works. I just used console app projrct instead of windows app.

Comment: I don't need to do anything. You might want to consider buying a better book.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-aFHUGJ09_Q

Comment: It seems that the io.h is working in that assembly program seen in the video. I wonder what you'll have to say about seeing it work in front of your eyes.

Comment: Nothing. I don't click on YouTube links. You could instead explain in your answer exactly how you managed to convince MASM to include a header file written entirely in C, specifically the `io.h` file from Visual Studio 2012, without generating errors.

Comment: updated main question.

Comment: @RossRidge : I think the confusion is that the `io.h`you are thinking of is not the same as what David is referring to..David should have said the `io.h` was one from the book. It is rather unfortunate the book chose `io.h` as a file name that also happens to be the same as one provided in the Visual Studio/C++ environment. I know another book does something similar but they at least chose a different name  using an `inc` extension and renamed it `asm_io.inc`

Comment: @MichaelPetch You're probably right that there's a different `io.h` involved here, but the OP "GeekDewd" is making a much different argument about it not working in "console applications". The reason why he didn't say that he using the `io.h` from the book because until you commented he had no idea it existed.

Comment: It is included in visual studio, you idiots! Buy the book and study it. You guys need to take classes. I am not adding anything to the existing language. I am simply opening a code file (.asm) in notepad and copy and pasting that into VS just how I described above, If that somehow adds io.h to my computer then.... why do we need programmers?

Comment: Whether I realize it or not I installed those files. Yes I realize I installed those files... When I downloaded VS 2012 directly from Microsoft's website. My book came with no CD, IONLY installed official microsoft VS directly from Microsoft's website. So I guess you could say "whether you realize it or not, I ONLY HAVE MICROSOFT'S OFFICIAL SOFTWARE"

Comment: And PS, your **question** says this: **_And I am using the books files and code._** Your question says you are using the books files and code but your last comment says you aren't. You really need to make up your mind.

Comment: Since you insist my book provides this to me, show me where I got it. Lookup the bock, no cd included, I bought it for $160 from my school brand new. No disc

Comment: I haven't added anything to VS, It's an official install downloaded from MS and haven't added ANYTHING TO IT. It worked in the past because I was using windows32, this program was console32. Look at the youtube video, it works and it's windows32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize! I just realized I can't use io.h because I am writing a console application, this code is for windows application.

For anyone else having this problem, if you are writing console program you can't use io.h, there is no input/output in console programs, if you need input/output you must use windows application.